# What would be the proper way to address this situation?

Tags: tense, backshifting

The fact is that the price for that item is still $7.99. I saw the price in the past and the price didn't change.

> A. I saw that the price for that item was $7.99.

> B. I saw that the price for that item is $7.99.

What would be the correct way to say this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only A) is correct.

> I saw that the price for that item was $7.99.

"Was" agrees in tense with "saw"; the sentence is about an action or actions that happened in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Was because the item could've changed price since your purchase.

Comment: Hi welcome to ELL! We expect our answers to be detailed and supported with research. Could you say a bit more why it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need "was" because it relates to when you saw it, not to what it is now. If you saw the item again and the price was the same you could say "I saw that the price for that item was still $7.99".

If you want to say that the price is still the same now, when you are not looking at it you would need a separate statement.

The only time you might be able to use "I saw the price is .." is immediately after you have seen it, for example if you and a friend are shopping in the same shop and you turned away from the price label to speak to your friend.